# Mysql use LAST_INSERT_ID in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, last-insert-id

I need to create a table based on the last id inserted into another main table, for this I created the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_create_campaign`
(
        IN  p_vName         VARCHAR(70),
        IN  p_iIdOper       INT(11),
        IN  p_iIdCount      INT(11),
        IN  p_iIdMoney      INT(11),
        IN  p_cPrefix       CHAR(2),
        IN  p_tComment      TINYTEXT,
        IN  p_iIdUser       VARCHAR(32),
        OUT p_return_code   TINYINT UNSIGNED
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE p_campaign INT(11);

    DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
    BEGIN
        -- ERROR
            set p_return_code = 1;
            rollback;
    END;

    DECLARE exit handler for sqlwarning
    BEGIN
            -- WARNING
            set p_return_code = 2;
            rollback;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;

        -- Campaign
        INSERT INTO `db_campaign` 
            (`vName`, `iIdOper`, `iIdCount`, `iIdMoney`, `cPrefix`, `tComment`, `iIdUser`, `dRegister`)
            VALUES
            (p_vName, p_iIdOper, p_iIdCount, p_iIdMoney, p_cPrefix, p_tComment, p_iIdUser, NOW());

        SET p_campaign := LAST_INSERT_ID();

        -- Sales
        SET @s = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ', 'db_sale_', p_campaign);
        PREPARE stm FROM @s;
        EXECUTE stm;

        SET @x = CONCAT(
                'CREATE TABLE ',
                'db_sale_', p_campaign,
                "(
                `iIdSale`           INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `dDate`             DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                `dSubtotal`         DECIMAL(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '00.00',
                `dTax`              DECIMAL(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '00.00',
                `dTotal`            DECIMAL(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '00.00',
                `iIdMoney`          INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `iIdOper`           INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `iIdBankCount`      INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `iIdGroup`          INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `iIdUser`           INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                `iIdUserReg`        VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
                `dRegister`         DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                PRIMARY KEY (`iIdSale`)
                ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;");        

        PREPARE stm FROM @x;
        EXECUTE stm;

    COMMIT;

    -- SUCCESS
    set p_return_code = 0;

END
```

But the problem is that only inserts the first record and fails to create the table. Where am I failing?

Comment: Did it throw any error? What is the output of `select p_return_code;`? Or comment the `sqlexception handler` block and see what happens.

Comment: I commented SQLException and have added: "SELECT p_return_code," at the end. But I do not return anything! only: "Time: 0.000ms Procedure Executed successfully Affected rows: 0"

Answer (score 5):

Replace this line: `SET p_campaign := LAST_INSERT_ID();`

With this one: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO p_campaign ;`

Answer (score 0):

if you use `SET` you need `=` instead of `:=`

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Executing `DROP` will implicitly `COMMIT` your transaction.
2. Try adding

   `DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm;`

after each `EXECUTE` statement.

Comment: I get the same result. The main problem is getting the last ID. I'm using the same stored procedure to insert directly other records directly to the latest ID but still does not work. Will be for the transaction?

Comment: If db_campaign is MyISAM, you can remove the `START TRANSACTION;`, `COMMIT;` and `ROLLBACK;`s, as they're effectively NOOPs. You could add  some logging, something like `INSERT INTO syslog SET script='myscript', line='lineno', message=CONCAT('last_insert_id()=', LAST_INSERT_ID());`

Comment: Yeah you're right. Investigating the MyISAM database does not support transactions.

Answer (score 0):

According to MySQL documentation of [last_insert_id()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

> If a stored procedure executes statements that change the value of LAST_INSERT_ID(), the changed value is seen by statements that follow the procedure call.

Use something like:

`SELECT id INTO p_campaign FROM db_campaign ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`

Or:

`SELECT max(id) INTO p_campaign FROM db_campaign;`